# .htaccess adding characters into url via rewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule in place that redirects `www.OLDsite.co.uk/locations.php?area=Barking,%20Essex` to `www.NEWsite.co.uk/locations.php?area=Barking,%20Essex`

...ideally, anyways. The problem exists at the end of the url. Instead of redirecting to the new site above like it should...it makes the following url instead: `www.NEWsite.co.uk/locations.php?area=Barking,%2520Essex`. I am really confused...here's my .htaccess file as it stands currently...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^locations.php/(.*)$ http://www.NEWsite.co.uk/locations.php$1 [R=permanent,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I'm new to mod_rewrites, but I'm willing to learn. I know it's a very powerful tool and it wouldn't be a bad thing to have in my developer arsenal. All tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change your RewriteRule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(locations\.php.*)$ http://www.localhost/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Important change here is flag `NE` which tell Apache to not encode the generated URI hence `%20` remains `%20` instead of becoming `%2520`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Just in case anyone else references this point for the same reason, it should be locations\.php(.*) ...just a small typo. Thank you again...my headache has been cured! :)

Comment: Sure mate. Also note that since you were using `locations.php` on both sides of your Rule I captured that as well in my group `$1` and just used `$1` on RHS without `locations.php`.

Comment: Also if it worked can you please mark this answer as Accepted whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that:

```
%25 is equal to "%" symbol
```

But that would equal %20 or a space.. Dont use spaces..use "+"